# Seemingly random X11 crashes that close all programs and return to login screen

Tags: 22.04, xorg, crash, lts, gpu

**The OS specs:**

```
camera@cameraControl:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

camera@cameraControl:~$ uname -a
Linux cameraControl 5.19.0-46-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 21 15:35:31 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**The system specs:**

```
camera@cameraControl:~$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path         Device      Class          Description
=======================================================
                             system         10M8A058JP (LENOVO_MT_10M8_BU_Think_FM_ThinkCentre M710s)
/0                           bus            3102
/0/0                         memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/3e                        memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/3e/0                      memory         4GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/3e/1                      memory         4GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/3e/2                      memory         4GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/3e/3                      memory         4GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/45                        memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/46                        memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/47                        memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/48                        processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
/0/100                       bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/2         /dev/fb0    display        HD Graphics 530
/0/100/14                    bus            200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0      usb1        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1                input          USB Receiver
/0/100/14/0/1/0  input18     input          Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023
/0/100/14/0/1/1  input19     input          Logitech Wireless Mouse
/0/100/14/0/2                bus            USB 2.0 Hub
/0/100/14/1      usb2        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                  generic        200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/16                    communication  200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17        scsi0       storage        200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/17/0      /dev/sda    disk           1024GB TEAM T253X2001T
/0/100/17/0/1                volume         512MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/17/0/2    /dev/sda2   volume         953GiB Extended partition
/0/100/17/0/2/5  /dev/sda5   volume         953GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/17/1      /dev/cdrom  disk           DVDRAM GUE0N
/0/100/1c                    bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5
/0/100/1c/0      enp1s0      network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1c.6                  bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #7
/0/100/1c.6/0    enp2s0      network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1c.7                  bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #8
/0/100/1c.7/0                multimedia     DeckLink Mini Recorder
/0/100/1f                    bridge         200 Series PCH LPC Controller (B250)
/0/100/1f/0                  system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/1                  communication  PnP device PNP0501
/0/100/1f/2                  system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/3                  system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/4                  system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/100/1f/5                  generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/100/1f/6                  system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/7                  system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/8                  system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/9                  system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/a                  system         PnP device PNP0c31
/0/100/1f.2                  memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3      card0       multimedia     200 Series PCH HD Audio
/0/100/1f.3/0    input21     input          HDA Intel PCH Front Mic
/0/100/1f.3/1    input22     input          HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
/0/100/1f.3/2    input23     input          HDA Intel PCH Line
/0/100/1f.3/3    input24     input          HDA Intel PCH Line Out
/0/100/1f.3/4    input25     input          HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone
/0/100/1f.3/5    input26     input          HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/0/100/1f.3/6    input27     input          HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/0/100/1f.3/7    input28     input          HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/0/100/1f.3/8    input29     input          HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/0/100/1f.4                  bus            200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
/1                           power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.
/2               input0      input          Sleep Button
/3               input1      input          Power Button
/4               input2      input          Power Button
/5               input20     input          Video Bus
```

**Problem:**
Seemingly at random, and more frequently in that last 2-3 months than the  previous year, all programs will exit and the system returns to the login prompt.

All the user sees is a black screen. Only by looking in syslog did I find out the Xserver is crashing. And that triggers dumping all programs, then logging off the user.

I preserved everything in /var/log immediately after logging in after an occurrence. It happened an hour or so earlier too.

***The Ask:***
I do not have much experience diagnosing what is causing this. Any and all input greatly appreciated.

**What I tried so far:**
Since this first started while we were recording OBS video to disk, my first idea was CPU over loading.  At that time we had changed recording quality to full HD. And after a crash, I could see recording was putting the CPU right up to 98/99% so it made sense to me it could easily max out and crash.  So I reduced the recording quality down several notches.  Now when recording, the CPU % stays under 75%, usually around 60%.

Then today, it crashed *TWICE* when I was not recording, once when OBS was not even running I think!  So much for my CPU % theory.

So I grabbed the entire /var/log folder.  (copied to my remote desktop) And looked in Syslog.  The last 2 minutes of the log look like a repeating cycle of something.  But at the "start" of the time line I find this:

```
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl kernel: [ 9321.667233] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Resetting rcs0 for preemption time out
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl kernel: [ 9321.667304] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Xorg[121129] context reset due to GPU hang
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl kernel: [ 9321.690592] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:1:85dffffb, in Xorg [121129]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE)
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) Backtrace:
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x139) [0x55d816c6e939]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__sigaction+0x50) [0x7f6f60242520]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (pthread_kill+0x12c) [0x7f6f60296a7c]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (raise+0x16) [0x7f6f60242476]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (abort+0xd3) [0x7f6f602287f3]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (?+0x0) [0x7f6f5de9c8b7]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (nouveau_drm_screen_create+0x45064f) [0x7f6f5eb5de3f]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so (__driDriverGetExtensions_d3d12+0xc7267) [0x7f6f5df727a7]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (glamor_destroy_pixmap+0x154) [0x7f6f5faaf604]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f6f5faea157]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (BlockHandler+0xa5) [0x55d816afcf25]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (WaitForSomething+0x119) [0x55d816c67fa9]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SendErrorToClient+0x117) [0x55d816af8277]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x3c4) [0x55d816afc544]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 14: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_init_first+0x90) [0x7f6f60229d90]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 15: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7f6f60229e40]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) 16: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x25) [0x55d816ae5605]
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE)
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE)
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: Fatal server error:
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE)
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE)
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]:  for help.
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/camera/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE)
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Jul  2 11:02:46 cameraControl /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[121129]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
Jul  2 11:02:47 cameraControl DesktopVideoUpdater: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
```

Which seems to start with an interesting error: **GPU HANG: ecode 9:1:85dffffb, in Xorg [121129]**

It also mentions looking at a X11 log *"/home/camera/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log"*:
I dont see any errors in this file. Its mostly this repeating a couple of times.

```
[  9351.416] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-2 using initial mode 1920x1080 +0+0
[  9351.416] (==) modeset(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  9351.416] (==) modeset(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[  9351.416] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  9351.416] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  9351.416] (II) Module "fb" already built-in
[  9351.416] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  9351.416] (II) Unloading fbdev
[  9351.416] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[  9351.416] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[  9351.416] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  9351.416] (II) Unloading vesa
[  9351.428] (==) modeset(0): Backing store enabled
[  9351.428] (==) modeset(0): Silken mouse enabled
[  9351.550] (II) modeset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
[  9351.550] (==) modeset(0): DPMS enabled
[  9351.550] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[  9351.550] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: iris
[  9351.550] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[  9351.551] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[  9351.551] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[  9351.551] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[  9351.551] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[  9351.551] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[  9351.551] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[  9351.551] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[  9351.552] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[  9351.552] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[  9351.552] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[  9351.552] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[  9351.552] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[  9351.552] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[  9351.552] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[  9351.552] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[  9351.553] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  9351.553] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  9351.553] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[  9351.553] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[  9351.553] (II) Initializing extension Present
[  9351.553] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[  9351.554] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[  9351.554] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[  9351.554] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  9351.554] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[  9351.554] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[  9351.554] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[  9351.563] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized iris
[  9351.563] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[  9351.563] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  9351.563] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[  9351.563] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[  9351.563] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[  9351.564] (II) modeset(0): Damage tracking initialized
[  9351.564] (II) modeset(0): Setting screen physical size to 508 x 285
[  9351.599] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[  9351.600] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  9351.600] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[  9351.600] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[  9351.601] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  9351.601]    compiled for 1.20.14, module version = 1.2.1
[  9351.601]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  9351.601]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[  9351.601] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[  9351.602] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event2 13:66 fd 29 paused 0
[  9351.602] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  9351.602] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[  9351.606] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  9351.606] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[  9351.606] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[  9351.606] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[  9351.606] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[  9351.606] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  9351.606] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  9351.608] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  9351.608] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[  9351.609] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event5)
[  9351.609] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  9351.609] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[  9351.610] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event5 13:69 fd 32 paused 0
[  9351.610] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[  9351.610] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[  9351.611] (II) event5  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  9351.611] (II) event5  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[  9351.611] (II) event5  - Video Bus: device removed
[  9351.611] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input20/event5"
[  9351.611] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[  9351.611] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  9351.611] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  9351.612] (II) event5  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  9351.612] (II) event5  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[  9351.613] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[  9351.613] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  9351.613] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[  9351.613] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 33 paused 0
[  9351.613] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  9351.613] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[  9351.614] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  9351.614] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[  9351.614] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[  9351.614] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[  9351.614] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[  9351.614] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  9351.614] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  9351.615] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  9351.615] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[  9351.616] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event0)
[  9351.616] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  9351.616] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[  9351.617] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 34 paused 0
[  9351.617] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[  9351.617] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[  9351.618] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  9351.618] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[  9351.618] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
[  9351.618] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0/event0"
[  9351.618] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[  9351.618] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  9351.618] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  9351.619] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  9351.619] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[  9351.621] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023 (/dev/input/event3)
[  9351.621] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  9351.621] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023'
[  9351.622] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 35 paused 0
[  9351.622] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: always reports core events
[  9351.622] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[  9351.624] (II) event3  - Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  9351.624] (II) event3  - Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: device is a keyboard
[  9351.624] (II) event3  - Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: device removed
[  9351.624] (II) libinput: Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: needs a virtual subdevice
[  9351.624] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0002/0003:046D:4023.0003/input/input18/event3"
[  9351.624] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[  9351.624] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  9351.624] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  9351.624] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  9351.624] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  9351.626] (II) event3  - Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  9351.626] (II) event3  - Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: device is a keyboard
[  9351.628] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Wireless Mouse (/dev/input/event4)
[  9351.628] (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[  9351.628] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Wireless Mouse'
[  9351.628] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 36 paused 0
[  9351.629] (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse: always reports core events
[  9351.629] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[  9351.630] (II) event4  - Logitech Wireless Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[  9351.630] (II) event4  - Logitech Wireless Mouse: device is a pointer
[  9351.631] (II) event4  - Logitech Wireless Mouse: device removed
[  9351.631] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0002/0003:046D:4091.0004/input/input19/event4"
[  9351.631] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Wireless Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[  9351.631] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  9351.631] (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  9351.631] (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  9351.631] (**) Logitech Wireless Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  9351.633] (II) event4  - Logitech Wireless Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[  9351.633] (II) event4  - Logitech Wireless Mouse: device is a pointer
[  9351.634] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Wireless Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[  9351.635] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  9351.635] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  9351.635] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[  9351.635] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  9351.635] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  9351.636] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event7)
[  9351.636] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  9351.636] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  9351.636] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event8)
[  9351.636] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  9351.636] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  9351.637] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event9)
[  9351.637] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  9351.637] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  9351.638] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event10)
[  9351.638] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  9351.638] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  9351.638] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event11)
[  9351.638] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  9351.638] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  9351.639] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event12)
[  9351.639] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  9351.639] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  9351.639] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event13)
[  9351.640] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  9351.640] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  9351.640] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event14)
[  9351.640] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  9351.640] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  9351.650] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  9351.650] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023'
[  9351.650] (II) systemd-logind: returning pre-existing fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67
[  9351.650] (**) Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: always reports core events
[  9351.650] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[  9351.650] (II) libinput: Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: is a virtual subdevice
[  9351.650] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0002/0003:046D:4023.0003/input/input18/event3"
[  9351.650] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[  9351.650] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  9351.651] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "ACR", prod id 1602
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  174.50  1920 1928 1960 2080  1080 1105 1113 1119 +hsync -vsync (83.9 kHz eP)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x480"x0.0   27.00  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x576"x0.0   27.00  720 732 796 864  576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync (31.2 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1720 1760 1980  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x0.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (33.8 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x0.0   74.25  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (28.1 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (56.2 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   71.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0   88.75  1440 1488 1520 1600  900 903 909 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz e)
[  9352.467] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
```

I need help understanding these logs and figuring this out.  This is a church computer used to record/stream services and events.  I'm a volunteer, one of many, keeping it all working and occaisionally improving the system.

Comment: Possibly related to this post: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/4858#note_1751229 
I will try locking my GPU frequency to MAX.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by the Intel CPU throttling back due to rising temperatures.  I posted more details.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1477826/890273

The fix I am testing is to install a GNOME plugin that lets you set a MIN and MAX CPU speed.  The default lets the CPU slow down to 20%. I changed that to 90%. So far so good. I need a hot day to find out if there is a "gotcha" with this idea.